# JQuery Navigation set Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I want that my Navigation is loaded without loading the page..all works. But the navigation element `<li> nav </li>`should get an class with another style..the "active". I tried this, but doesn't work, you cann see what happens at my [page](http://nitram0598.zapto.org/)
Code:

```
            $('#content').children('section').not('#home').hide();
            $(".a").hasClass('navigation-element').parent().removeClass('active');
            $(".a").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                if ($(this).hasClass('navigation-element')){
                    var $target = $('#' + $(this).attr('href')).stop(true, true);
                    var $secs = $('#content > section').not($target).stop(true,   true).filter(':visible');
                    if ($secs.length) {
                        $secs.fadeOut(function () {
                            $target.fadeIn();
                            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
                        });
                    } else {
                        $target.fadeIn();
                    }
                } else if ($(this).hasClass('hide')){
                    $(this).parent().fadeOut();
                }
            });
```

The Errors are in Line 2 and 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 2: hasClass returns a boolean value, you need to use class filters

Line 12: here `this` does not refer to the clicked `li` element, you need to use a closure variable refer to the clicked element

```
//initial setup
$('#content').children('section').not('#home').hide();
$('.active:has(a.anavigation-element)').removeClass('active');
$('.navigation-element[href="home"]').parent().addClass('active');

$('.navigation-element').click(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();

    var $target = $('#' + $(this).attr('href')).stop(true, true);
    var $secs = $('#content > section').not($target).stop(true, true).filter(':visible');

    if ($secs.length) {
        //remove existing active from the prev element
        $('.active:has(a.navigation-element)').removeClass('active');
        $secs.fadeOut(function () {
            $target.fadeIn();
            $this.parent().addClass('active');
        });
    } else {
        $target.fadeIn();
        $this.parent().addClass('active');
    }
});
```